# How to remove commits from rebased branch and rebase again

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

I have branches

```
B1 --c01--c02--c03--c04 
B2 --c11--c12--c13--c14
```

I rebased the branch B2 with B1 so

```
B2 --c01--c02--c03--c04--c11--c12--c13--c14
```

Both branches are developing simultaneously and now there are huge changes in B1 that have to be rebased into B2

so, I need to remove all old  `--c01--c02--c03--c04` and replace them with new data!!

Can anyone help me how to do it?

Comment: Why do c01 through c04 change? Commits in Git never change and history on a branch should not change (unless a developer moves a branch, e.g. through rebasing or reset).

Comment: Actually, there have been lots of rebasing in that branch.. new code.. improving existing code.. etc.

Comment: Editing published history makes life unnecessarily complicated for other developers. You can improve code by creating new commits, no need to change existing commits.

Comment: thats a different story dude.. its already done! I need to rebase it.

Comment: It's just an advice for the future.

Comment: If that could be done, I am going to be the first person to shout!! Cant help myself. sorry

Answer (score 1):

Usually, history should not change. Changing history makes collaborating more complicated than it could and should be.

But given the fact that history has already changed, and you want to replay a bunch of commits on top of the rewritten branch, you can use `git rebase` with the `--onto` option:

```
git rebase --onto new-c04 old-c04 B2
# or: git rebase --onto new-c04 c11^ B2
```

The above command will take all commits between `old-c04` (exclusive) and the tip of the `B2` branch (inclusive) and replay them onto commit `new-c04`. It will also move the `B2` branch pointer to the new tip of the new history (including your commits).

You might want to look into a *patch queuing* system such as guilt or TopGit.

Answer (score 0):

If you've modified B2 locally in a way that is inconsistent with the remote there are a number of things you can do.  One method would be:

```
git checkout B2 # make sure
git branch broken # create a branch to remember this point
git reset --hard @{u} # reset everything on B2 back to the position on the remote head
git pull --rebase # B2 will now be as the remote
```

I'm assuming when you say --c01--c02--c03--c04 need replacing with other commits these are coming from the remote repo.  So what remains for B2 is to replay c11--c12--c13--c14 back onto the branch. You could cherry-pick or rebase these changes:

```
git rev-list broken~4..broken | git cherry-pick --stdin
```

B1 will also need to be reset if it is a remote branch.